# Sinatra syntax error: unexpected character

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have a pesky problem I really don't understand the error message I'm getting some googling has only left me more confusing hoping something might be able to lay these snakes out straight for me!

I'm just playing around with Sinatra I'm running the following code:

```
set :haml, :format =&gt; :html5
    get "/" do
    haml :index
end
```

But when I run the code I seem to get this error message:

```
app.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting $end
set :haml, :format =&gt; :html5
                    ^
```

I honestly don't get it? What could this mean? I have ruby 1.9.1 installed and using haml and sinatra gems?

Comment: what is `&gt;` doing here? change that to `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `&gt;` with `>`.

```
set :haml, :format => :html5

get "/" do
    haml :index
end
```